# Mojolicious Parameter Validation

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I have the following code :

```
get '/:foo' => sub {
  my $c   = shift;
  my $v = $c->validation;
  
  my $foo = $c->param('y');
  $c->render(text => "Hello from $foo.") if  $v->required('y')->like(q/[A-Z]/);
};
```

and want to verify the `y` parameter of the http request I connect to the above web page using: http://myserver:3000?x=2&y=1

It prints  `Hello from 1.` Even though there is `$v->required('y')->like(q/[A-Z]/);`

What could be my problem here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mojolicious validation uses [a fluent interface](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Validator/Validation), so most methods return the validation object. Objects are truthy by default, so your condition is always true.

Instead, you can check

- `->is_valid()` – whether validation for the current topic was sucessful, or
- `->has_error()` – whether there were any validation errors.

You introduce a new validation topic by calling `->required('name')` or `->optional('name')` on the validation object. So you could write:

```
$c->render(text => "Hello from $foo.")
  if $v->required('y')->like(q/[A-Z]/)->is_valid;
```

or

```
$v->required('y')->like(q/[A-Z]/);
$c->render(text => "Hello from $foo.") unless $v->has_error;
```